# Expected type 'array'. Found 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' Laravel Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I was using raw SQL statements in my Laravel 8.54 project like:

`$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM` ..`WHERE`..`= '$number' AND`.. `like '$SelectedMonth%' ORDER BY ..ASC");`

Then I convert them using Laravel Query Builder to something like:

```
$data = DB::table("..")
                        ->select("..")
                        ->where("..", "=", $number)
                        ->where("..", "like", $SelectedMonth.'%')
                        ->orderBy("..", "asc")
                        ->get();
```

Before the change, the SQL query returned an array of objects and I was able to use Sort() and some other function.

Now I get the error: `sort(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, Illuminate\\Support\\Collection given` and `Expected type 'array'. Found 'Illuminate\Support\Collection'`

How can I convert the given result back to an array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `get` method returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` instance containing the results of the query where each result is an instance of the PHP `stdClass` object.

To convert a collection to the array use `toArray()` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-toarray

You can sort a collection as well with `sortBy()` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby